# Apache Camel Manually NACK messages while processing

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Queue in RabbitMQ and DLX and DLK are set for that queue.

My requirement is: NACK messages if some conditions are not met. After 3 retries, set requeue flag to false and route the message to DLX. Some other process will pick messages from DLX and take necessary action(s).

I have created a route to get messages from the queue and process it (transform). I have set autoAck to false while creating the endpoint.

My questions are:

- How to NACK the message during message processing (mid route)?
- Based on what i read on internet, the suggestion is to throw an
  exception to NACK the message. Is this the right and only option to NACK
  messages mid route?

Thanks